# String array inside obj is emptied/not populated between create and pre-validate middleware

Tags: javascript, json, express, mongoose, middleware

I am pretty new to JS, mongoose and express and I am currently trying to implement some pre validation iterations over parts of my objects, namely the category array. The Schema expects an Array of ObjectIDs, but I wanted to allow providing category names instead of ObjectIDs here as well because the category database part is rather simple as names are unique anyway and using ObjectIDs here feels a little clunky for user side. Unfortunately inside my pre-validation middleware those arrays are for some reasons empty, while they should have contained the Strings I intended to compare to the categories collection to find the according IDs.

So I had a look at the object before trying to create a document in my router, where it was looking just as it was supposed to look.

Part of my router which receives multipart form-data (2 files and 2 Parts of JSON):

```
router.post('/', uploadFiles.fields([{ name: 'gszfile', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'imagefile', maxCount: 1 }]), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { projectdata, versiondata } = req.body;
    const projectData = JSON.parse(projectdata); 
    console.log(`projectdata: ${JSON.stringify(projectData)}`)
    console.log(`projectData.categories: ${projectData.categories}`) //here categories is not empty
    const newProject = await Project.create(projectData);
```

And here is my pre-validate middleware from inside my schema:

```
project_schema.pre('validate', async function(next) {
    const categories = this.categories;
    console.log(`this: ${JSON.stringify(this)}`) //here categories is empty
    console.log(`categories: ${categories}`)
});
```

This my console log from the router:

```
projectdata: {"title":"activator","shortdescription":"A stochastic model of the activator-substrate process","gszfile":"activator.gsz","author":"","description":"","howitworks":"","thingstonotice":"","thingstotry":"","extendingthemodel":"","relatedmodels":"","creditsandreferences":"","createdAt":"2009-04-20T00:00:00.000+01:00","updatedAt":"2009-04-20T00:00:00.000+01:00","categories":["Intern","FormalSystems"],"access":{"public":true,"readAccess":[],"writeAccess":[]},"imagefile":"activator.png"}
projectData.categories: Intern,FormalSystems
```

And here my log from the middleware:

```
this: {"title":"activator","shortdescription":"A stochastic model of the activator-substrate process","description":"","howitworks":"","thingstonotice":"","thingstotry":"","extendingthemodel":"","relatedmodels":"","creditsandreferences":"","categories":[],"tags":[],"imagefile":"activator.png","versions":[],"access":{"public":true,"readAccess":[],"writeAccess":[]},"_id":"65e98a15a58ee683b2bfa0e8","createdAt":"2009-04-19T23:00:00.000Z","updatedAt":"2009-04-19T23:00:00.000Z"}
categories:
```

The weird part is the other fields are carried over correctly, so I am a little lost what could be a reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Why do you call `JSON.stringify()` on something that's already a JSON string? It would be better to use `JSON.stringify(projectData)`

Comment: I corrected that typo, this does not fix the problem though